# Contact form 7 receiving field via mail

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a few conditions and fields with my contact form, all is working fine. However I want to recieve the country and not the email address when the email is sent. Please see here:-

```
[select* recipient first_as_label 
"Market*|test@hotmail.co.uk" 
"GB|GB@hotmail.co.uk" 
"Ireland|ireland@emeraldcolour.com" ]
```

My mail code is:-

```
<p>Email Address: <strong>[your-email]</strong></p>
```

But this comes through as the email address and not GB, Ireland etc... I need to have it this way, as whatever country is chosen will recieve the email.

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Contact 7 documentation](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) explains how to retrieve any info from the selector.

You can try with [*raw*{field name}], in your case ([_raw_recipient].

```
<p>Email Address: <strong>[_raw_recipient]</strong></p>
```

P.S. I change the field name according your code

I hope this can help you