# WordPress Contact-Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to add a field with 2 emails for reception but I don't find it.

```
[select* recipient
"Problem|tata@gmail.com"
"Idea|titi@gmail.com"
"Other|toto@gmail.com"]
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
[select* recipient
"Problem|tata@gmail.com"
"Idea|titi@gmail.com"
"Other|toto@gmail.com|tutu@gmail.com"]
```

It gives me an error and I don't find any syntax to do this.

How to send to two email addresses with a specific field with contact form 7 ?

EDIT : I found the solution here : [Contact Form 7 send to multiple contacts at once upon user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969194/contact-form-7-send-to-multiple-contacts-at-once-upon-user-selection?rq=1)

Comment: Little bit confused by your question, so to clarify.. are trying to send one email to two people, or to add two email addresses into dropdown/select?

Comment: I'm trying to send two emails after selecting one field.

Comment: And you only want to send it to two people if a specific field is selected? or send to two people all the time?

Comment: In specific field

Comment: You can't out of the box. You need custom development to do that.

Comment: And with additionnal settings, I can't make rules with labels for example ?

Comment: Please make your question clear and understandable, add more description so can help you.

Comment: I just edited the initial subject.

Comment: I find the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969194/contact-form-7-send-to-multiple-contacts-at-once-upon-user-selection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To get value before pipe, you can use [*raw*{field name}], that means [_raw_recipient] in your form

Comment: I don't understand the answer, I have to change the select method ?

Comment: check this https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276425/contact-form-7-receiving-field-via-mail